# Error configuring jython 2.5.1 on Eclipse 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, configuration, jython, pydev, interpreter

I'm trying to set up the Jython interpreter on a Eclipse 3.7.2 installed on Ubuntu 12.04 via Ubuntu Software Center. Eclipse is eclipse-platform 3.7.2-1 version. PyDev has been installed as indicated by the user manual (or at least that is what I beleive), and I've tried to set up the interpreter with both the Update and the nightly build of PyDev. Right now, PyDev version is:
PyDev for Eclipse   2.6.0.2012050900    org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group  Aptana

Jyton is also installed:
panton@maleficio:~$ dpkg -l |grep -i jython
ii  jython                                 2.5.1-2ubuntu2                          Python seamlessly integrated with Java

and I can find it in a "proper" directory:

panton@maleficio:~$ ls -1 /usr/share/java/jython*
/usr/share/java/jython-2.5.1.jar
/usr/share/java/jython.jar
panton@maleficio:~$

(the second file is just a link to the first).

This said, when I try to create a new project, File -> New -> Project -> PyDev -> PyDev Project, then Next, I'm offered three project types: Python, that seems OK, and shows a combo box to choose the interpreter, and Jython and Iron Python, that (both) kindly remind me that "Please configure an interpreter in the related preferences before proceding.".

For the next paragraphs, I'll stick to the Jython option, because Iron Python has no "official" distribution for Precise Pagolin (Ubuntu 12.04) already.

OK then, I go to the Window->Preferences, and select the Interpreter-Jython, then New, I choose a proper name, Jython 2.5.1, then the right path, /usr/share/java/jython-2.5.1.jar,

### press OK, and get this message:

Error getting info on interpreter. Common reasons include:
- Using an unsupported version (Jython should be at least 2.1, and so it is: it is 2.5.1 version)
- Specifying an invalid interpreter. Not at all, because I choose the real file, not the link.
.......................................

### The error log says:

```
    See error log for details.
    No output was in the standard output when trying to create the interpreter info.
    The error output contains:>>error importing site
        at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPath(PySystemState.java:513)
        at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPathLazy(PySystemState.java:502)
        at org.python.core.util.RelativeFile.<init>(RelativeFile.java:21)
        at org.python.core.packagecache.PathPackageManager.packageExists(PathPackageManager.java:43)
        at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.packageExists(SysPackageManager.java:159)
        at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.__findattr_ex__(PyJavaPackage.java:132)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__findattr__(PyObject.java:869)
        at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.lookupName(PackageManager.java:136)
        at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:39)
        at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ext/posix/util/Platform
    <<

------------------------------------------------------
The Workspace log on Eclipse says:
-------------------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

Error
Sun May 20 08:39:09 CEST 2012
No output was in the standard output when trying to create the interpreter info.
The error output contains:>>error importing site
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPath(PySystemState.java:513)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPathLazy(PySystemState.java:502)
    at org.python.core.util.RelativeFile.<init>(RelativeFile.java:21)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PathPackageManager.packageExists(PathPackageManager.java:43)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.packageExists(SysPackageManager.java:159)
    at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.__findattr_ex__(PyJavaPackage.java:132)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__findattr__(PyObject.java:869)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.lookupName(PackageManager.java:136)
    at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:39)
    at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ext/posix/util/Platform
<<

java.lang.RuntimeException: No output was in the standard output when trying to create the interpreter info.
The error output contains:>>error importing site
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPath(PySystemState.java:513)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPathLazy(PySystemState.java:502)
    at org.python.core.util.RelativeFile.<init>(RelativeFile.java:21)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PathPackageManager.packageExists(PathPackageManager.java:43)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.packageExists(SysPackageManager.java:159)
    at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.__findattr_ex__(PyJavaPackage.java:132)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__findattr__(PyObject.java:869)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.lookupName(PackageManager.java:136)
    at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:39)
    at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ext/posix/util/Platform
<<
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.AbstractInterpreterManager.createInfoFromOutput(AbstractInterpreterManager.java:415)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.JythonInterpreterManager.doCreateInterpreterInfo(JythonInterpreterManager.java:77)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.JythonInterpreterManager.internalCreateInterpreterInfo(JythonInterpreterManager.java:46)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.AbstractInterpreterManager.createInterpreterInfo(AbstractInterpreterManager.java:369)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.pythonpathconf.ObtainInterpreterInfoOperation.run(ObtainInterpreterInfoOperation.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

---

### Jruby has already been installed, it's version is:

panton@maleficio:~$ dpkg -l |grep -i jruby

### ii  jruby                                  1.5.6-2                                 100% pure-Java implementation of Ruby

and the jar file /usr/lib/jruby/lib/jruby.jar is present and contains the classes referenced at both error dumps.

As requested, I execute this command:
~$ java -Dpython.home=/usr/share/java -classpath /usr/share/java/jython-2.5.1.jar:$CLASSPATH org.python.util.jython plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc/interpreterInfo.py
error importing site
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPath(PySystemState.java:513)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.getPathLazy(PySystemState.java:502)
    at org.python.core.util.RelativeFile.(RelativeFile.java:21)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PathPackageManager.packageExists(PathPackageManager.java:43)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.packageExists(SysPackageManager.java:153)
    at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.**findattr_ex**(PyJavaPackage.java:132)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.**findattr**(PyObject.java:869)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.lookupName(PackageManager.java:136)
    at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:39)
    at org.python.core.JavaImporter.find_module(JavaImporter.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/ext/posix/util/Platform

Any help on this will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that Jython is for some reason conflicting with JRuby (which seems really weird to me).

Can you try running:

```
java -Dpython.home=/usr/share/java -classpath /usr/share/java/jython-2.5.1.jar:%CLASSPATH% org.python.util.jython plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc/interpreterInfo.py
```

and paste the output you get from running that from the command line?

---

Edit:

Hummm, it seems it's not a PyDev issue (I think that if you changed interpreterInfo.py in that command line for a file simply with 'import sys;import os.path", you'd have the same error -- please do check that).

My guess is that Jython and JRuby are conflicting... you can try setting your CLASSPATH to remove JRuby when executing Jython (if you're able to get it working in a shell with that command line, you should be able to start Eclipse from that shell and properly configure the Jython interpreter).

---

Edit 2:

Ok, I took a quick look at Jython and it seems this is a Jython bug. on the version you have there... see: https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/fd2130e12b7c/src/org/python/core/PySystemState.java (it has an **import org.jruby.ext.posix.util.Platform**, which should definitely not be there). In the latest version it the repository, it was already changed for **import jnr.posix.util.Platform**, so, apparently, it's mostly a matter of getting a proper Jython version (it may be that the one in the linux repo is not ok -- or at least, you **need** to have JRuby on the PYTHONPATH for Jython to work, which is really awkward (but should already be fixed in the Jython side).

Comment: I've added the output at the end of the question.

Comment: Well, after removing jRuby from the system, I still get the same error. I suppose somehow jython and jruby are not conflicting, It's just a broken dependency: the jython configuration seems to need jruby, and can't find it in the classpath. I'm trying to see a way to add jruby.jar to the classpath, but it does not seem so obvious as if it were a simple java standalone program. I'll go on when I get back from work.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and I solved it by uninstalling the Jython version offered in the Ubuntu 12.04 repository and reinstalling Jython using the version given in the website of the project. Fabio Zadrozny is right about the bug. Thank you.